# Using Cloud SQL Proxy with Coorporate Proxy

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to connect against Cloud SQL with the Cloud SQL Proxy but the problem is that in my company we use a private VPN to connect to Google Services, so I need to have enable the VPN and their proxy.

When I execute

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<CONNECTION-NAME>=tcp:5432
```

If I use a environment variable to declare the proxy and the user and password, it returns me,

```
errors parsing config:
    Get "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<PROJECT>/instances/<REGION>~<SQL-INSTANCE>?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

And if I delete the environment variable, it returns,

```
errors parsing config:
    Get "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<PROJECT>/instances/<REGION>~<INSTANCE-SQL>?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": dial tcp <IP>:<PORT>: i/o timeout
```

Anyone resolve to execute the cloud_sql_proxy with another proxy?

Comment: Port `3307` should be open from your corporate network (egress). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396551/7031308.

Comment: But also for PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yes, that port is [used by the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#troubleshooting) to connect to the proxy server. If that solves the issue, please let us know.

Comment: I reached to have a connection with the cloud_sql_proxy, but when I try to connect to the proxy to get a connection with the database, now it returns me this console log

Comment: 2021/01/12 11:38:55 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for <INSTANCE-NAME>
2021/01/12 11:38:55 Ready for new connections
2021/01/12 11:39:02 New connection for "<INSTANCE-NAME>"
2021/01/12 11:39:48 New connection for "<INSTANCE-NAME>"
2021/01/12 11:40:18 couldn't connect to "<INSTANCE-NAME>": dial tcp <PUBLIC-IP>:3307: connect: operation timed out

Comment: Could you please share the result of this command "telnet PUBLIC IP 3307"? I want to take a look